# Create React App not installing complete files

Tags: reactjs, cmd

When I type `npx create-react-app my-app` the command only installs :
a node module folder, a package.json and a package-lock.json.
No src, and no public.
I've tried reinstalling Node.js, I downloaded the correct bit version but something's wrong. Can anybody suggest a fix. Thank you.

Comment: What is the output of create-react-app?

Comment: node_modules, public, src, .gitgnore, package.json, package-lock.json and a readme file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$ npm install -g create-react-app
$ create-react-app my-app-name
$ cd my-app-name
$ npm start
```

Comment: My Powershell's permission to run the script was somehow disabled. It worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome, consider approving the answer.